# ¿Que es _VIEW_PATH_ en require_once? _

Tags: php, html, pdo, aplicación-web

me encontraba practicando ejemplos en php y me encontre con este ejemplo de require_once, pero me generó dudas para que es el _VIEW_PATH_ :

```
  public function index() {
            $model = $this->empleado->listar();

            require_once _VIEW_PATH_ . 'header.php';
            require_once _VIEW_PATH_ .'home/index.php';
            require_once _VIEW_PATH_ . 'footer.php';
        }
```

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, se los agradezco.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé `_VIEW_PATH_` no es parte de PHP. Puede tratarse de una constante que tengas definida en cualquier parte de tu código para almacenar una parte de la ruta.  Como su nombre lo indica, puede que esa constante almacene la ruta al directorio de las `Vistas` de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que esta haciendo es concatenando la ruta del folder donde estan las vistas con el nombre del modulo. Si intentas imprimir el valor, veras como te retorna una ruta:

```
echo _VIEW_PATH_ . 'header.php'; // ruta del archivo completo.
```

Y ya seguro sabras que hacer `required_once`.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esta forma :

```
require_once('header.php');
require_once('home/index.php');
require_once('footer.php');
```